# Find out who merged a branch into another in a git repository

Tags: git, version-control, devops, continuous-deployment, atlassian-sourcetree

I was working on a feature branch, yet to be completed, but someone in the team merged my branch into the "Develop" branch.

The merging point shows my id (I believe being the last committer on the branch), but I didn't merge it myself.

Although, I figured out who merged it by email notifications, but is there a way to know directly? just in case, there is no email notification in future, and you need to clear yourself, and don't just take unfair responsibility.

Comment: Did the merge result in a merge commit, or was it a fast forward merge?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I believe merge commit.

Comment: To avoid situations like this you should configure your git repository hosting systems to disallow push on core branches, such as master and/or develop, and only allow modifications to these branches through a pull request. This would add an un-ignorable process around modifying these branches so that nobody would ever need to "clear themselves".

Comment: If there is a merge commit, that commit was made by the person making the merge. Unfortunately, git allows you to fake these values, so if someone wanted to blame you for this, they very well could. You would have to make up your own mind on whether this is plausible or not.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I did make a pull request, which required more updates after it was created, and not meant to be merged. - my question is who did the merge?

Comment: Was the PR completed?

Comment: The reason I'm asking these questions is that your question doesn't have an easy answer. It depends. If someone did a fast forward merge, then no trace of who performed that is in the git repository. It may, however, be in the logs on your server if you have such a thing, who pushed the changes that fast forwarded develop. If there is a merge commit, the name on that commit should be the person who did the merge, but if someone wanted to blame you for this they can fake this value. Again, the push logs might contain information to use.

Comment: So if there is a merge commit, check the name on that commit. That's as close to an answer you'll get from me. The rest of my questions/advice is to look into avoiding this kind of situation in the future, precisely because it is easier to prevent the situation than to figure out who introduced it.